# Accessing nest class methods

Tags: javascript, angular, model

This seems like a ridiculous post but I have spent the last couple days attempting to figure out how to access a nested classes methods.  There are two models in this application, a User and a PersonalInfo model.  They are defined as follows:

**User**

```
export class User implements Deserializable {
  public id: number;
  public emailAddress: string;
  public username: string;
  public password: string;
  public userInfo: PersonalInfo;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    return Object.assign(this, input);
  }

  get fullName() {
    return this.userInfo.fullName();
  }
}
```

**PersonalInfo**

```
import {Deserializable} from "./deserializable.model";

export class PersonalInfo implements Deserializable {
  public infoId: number;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public street: string;
  public city: string;
  public stateId: number;
  public zipCode: string;
  public mobileNumber: string;
  public homeNumber: string;
  public workNumber: string;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    return Object.assign(this, input);
  }

  /**
   * Return the user's full name.
   */
  fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

** HTML File **

```
<button class="btn-success"(click)="getUser(0)">Get User</button>
<button (click)="getUserList()">User List</button>
<div *ngIf="userList && userList.length > 0">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let user of userList">
      <td>{{user.username}}</td>
      <td>{{user.emailAddress}}</td>
      <td>{{user.fullName}}</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

The angular application returns a single User object.  I attempt to call the "fullName" method which should print the user's first and last name concatenated together.  However, I get the following error: "this.userInfo.fullName is not a function. (In 'this.userInfo.fullName()', 'this.userInfo.fullName' is undefined)".  Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Does `this.userInfo`, also return `undefined`?

Comment: userInfo is defined.  It has all of the expected data from the DB.  There are no IDE errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when use Object.assign(this, input) in your method deserialize of User.

I think that you can re-write like

```
deserialize(input: any): this {
    if (input["userInfo"]) {
      this.userInfo =
        this.userInfo == null
          ? new PersonalInfo().deserialize(input["userInfo"])
          : this.userInfo.deserialize(input["userInfo"]);
      delete input["userInfo"];
    }
    else
    {
      if (!this.userInfo)
        this.userInfo=new PersonalInfo()
    }
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }
```

This allow you make, e.g.

```
this.userList.push(new User().deserialize(
     {id:1,emailAddress:'qqq@qqq.com'
      userInfo:{firstName:'firstName',lastName:'lastName'}
     }))
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2jptq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `fullName` with parenthesis, since it is a function not a property, so your html should look like this

```
<div *ngIf="userList && userList.length > 0">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let user of userList">
      <td>{{user.username}}</td>
      <td>{{user.emailAddress}}</td>
      <td>{{user.fullName()}}</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Because the function in User.model.ts is a "getter" function it does not need nor will accept the parentheses.